# How to have a space between two inputs in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm very new to coding so I'm hoping that someone can help me.

I'm trying to create an expense tracker type of thing and have ended up with two inputs side by side with an add and remove button. when I click "add" the two inputs are combined but they stuck together and I'm wanting to have a space between them.

for example. If I click "Rent" in the first input and then "1000" in the second input, I get Rent1000. but I want it to say "Rent 1000"  for what it's worth, I'm hoping to be able to add the numbers to keep a running total.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Here is the code I have so far.

```js
function addItem() {
  var ul = document.getElementById("income-list");
  var income = document.getElementById("income");
  var amount = document.getElementById("amount");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.setAttribute('id', income.value);
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(income.value));
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(amount.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);
}

function removeItem() {
  var ul = document.getElementById("income-list");
  var income = document.getElementById("income");
  var amount = document.getElementById("amount");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  ul.removeChild(item);
}
```

```html
<table border="0px">
  <ul id="income-list"></ul>
  <ul id="expense-list"><ul>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="income" placeholder="Category"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="amount" placeholder="Amount"></td>
    <td><button onclick="addItem()">add</button></td>
    <td><button onclick="removeItem()">remove</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Instead of creating two text nodes you can use one. Something like `document.createTextNode(income.value + '  ' + amount.value)`. The quotes create a string with a space in it and `+` concatenates strings

Comment: `li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(income.value + " "));`  Or combine them as @charlietfl suggests.

Comment: Thank you!! I went ahead and combined them with the + '   ' + and it worked great. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Another way:
`li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(income.value));
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" "));
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(amount.value));`

Answer (score 0):

```
var li = document.createElement("li");
li.setAttribute('id', income.value);
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(income.value));
li.appendChild( document.createTextNode( '\u00A0' ) );
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(amount.value));
```

If you want/need more spaces, use several

```
 \u00A0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, explanation is included in the comments:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table border="0px">

<ul id="income-list"></ul>
<ul id="expense-list"><ul>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="income" placeholder="Category"></td>
<td><input type="number" id="amount" placeholder="Amount"></td> <!--- input type should be number so you can add them -->
<td><button onclick="addItem()">add</button></td>
<td><button onclick="removeItem()">remove</button></td>
</tr>
</table>


<script>

    // initialize an array to keep track of all amounts 
    allAmounts = [];

    // initialize a total for summing purpose
    var total = 0;

    function addItem(){
    var ul = document.getElementById("income-list");
    var income = document.getElementById("income");
    var amount = document.getElementById("amount");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.setAttribute('id',income.value);
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(income.value));
    // just add an empty space here
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" "));
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(amount.value));
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" Total:"));

    // parseFloat to convert string to floating point number
    // push amount added into an array
    allAmounts.push(parseFloat(amount.value));
    
    // reset the total otherwise it would be a wrong total
    total = 0; 

    // sum all amounts together in the array
    for(var i in allAmounts) {       
        total += allAmounts[i];
    }
    
    // create a new text node for total and append to li
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(total))
    ul.appendChild(li);
}

function removeItem(){
    var ul = document.getElementById("income-list");
    var income = document.getElementById("income");
    var amount = document.getElementById("amount");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    ul.removeChild(item);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or this if you want to display the total on a single line instead of on every row:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table border="0px">

<ul id="income-list"></ul>
<ul id="expense-list"><ul>

<!-- to display total income-->
<p id="total-income"></p>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="income" placeholder="Category"></td>
<td><input type="number" id="amount" placeholder="Amount"></td> <!--- input type should be number so you can add them -->
<td><button onclick="addItem()">add</button></td>
<td><button onclick="removeItem()">remove</button></td>
</tr>
</table>


<script>

    // initialize an array to keep track of all amounts 
    allAmounts = [];

    // initialize a total for summing purpose
    var total = 0;

    function addItem(){
    var ul = document.getElementById("income-list");
    var income = document.getElementById("income");
    var amount = document.getElementById("amount");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    // p element for total income
    var p = document.getElementById("total-income");
    li.setAttribute('id',income.value);
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(income.value));
    // just add an empty space here
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" "));
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(amount.value));

    // parseFloat to convert string to floating point number
    // push amount added into an array
    allAmounts.push(parseFloat(amount.value));
    
    // reset the total otherwise it would be a wrong total
    total = 0; 

    // sum all amounts together in the array
    for(var i in allAmounts) {       
        total += allAmounts[i];
    }
    
    // remove child if p already has a total, to reset the total
    if (p.hasChildNodes){
        p.innerHTML = "";
    }
    // create a new text node for total and append to li
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Total: " +total));
    ul.appendChild(li);
}

function removeItem(){
    var ul = document.getElementById("income-list");
    var income = document.getElementById("income");
    var amount = document.getElementById("amount");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    ul.removeChild(item);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I have alot to learn turns out.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the simplest solution :

Change this :

```
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(income.value));
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(amount.value));
```

to this :

```
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(income.value + ' ' + amount.value));
```